# is permanent generation part of memory reserved using xmx parameter?

Tags: java, memory-management

In java we can define max memory that process can take using xmx parameter. For perm gen we can define the MaxPermSize. So is the perm gen space is also part of memory allocated using
xmx parameter.

so is xmx = young + old OR young + old + perm OR young + old + perm + Stack space ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is the perm gen space is also part of memory allocated using xmx parameter.

No, the [permanent generation](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) space is a separate memory area. Here is a nice picture illustrating it visually:

[image]

Source: [Process heap, Eden, Tenured and Permgen](http://acupof.blogspot.com/2010/06/process-heap-eden-tenured-and-permgen.html).

Comment: Nice pic. For the lazy, here's a direct link to the full size version: http://i.imgur.com/pmJMC.png

Comment: @BalusC You mean too lazy for right-click > View Image? :) Will make the picture clickable for these über lazy.

Comment: Actually, I drag and drop the image in a new Firefox tab :)

Comment: @BalusC This saves one click if you have a tab open. But you have to move the mouse!

Comment: It's not necessary to have a tab open. Just drop in tab bar. And, my mouse is fast .. very fast :)